# What is the distribution when a Gaussian is passed through Sigmoid activation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normal-distribution

## Problem

This is an interview question my friend asked me since she messed up with it. To be more specific,

> What is the resulting distribution when a Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is transformed by Sigmoid $t(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$.

I tried to derive and got the following 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log y&=x-\log (1+e^x)\\
x&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}\exp(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})
\end{aligned}
$$
But the $\log(\cdot)$ seems to be intractable when I plug $x$ in.

I also tried to simulate this process and got

[image]

It seems that the resulting distribution is still Gaussian (with some elevation and shrinking in magnitude). But I still would like to know the theoretical derivation.

Could someone help me and my friend? Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. Your question (specifically the quoted part) uses the same symbol ($\sigma$) for two entirely different things. This will likely lead to disaster. 2. By "passed through" I take it you mean "transformed by", i.e. if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ you're seeking the density of  $Y=t(X)$ where $t(x) = 1/[1+\exp(-x)]$?

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry about the confusion. Will update the question.

Comment: Do you  seek methodology  (*how do I compute the density of a transformed random variable*?) or just the answer -- it's (a well known distribution with its own wikipedia page and many questions about it on site).

Comment: @Glen_b I didn't know this. Could you provide a pointer to this page. Also, it would be great if you could help me with the derivation.

Comment: 1. An example of a previous question is here: [Distribution of a logit transform of a normal random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62043/distribution-of-a-logit-transform-of-a-normal-variable) 2. Wikipedia on [How to transform random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables) 3. Wikipedia on the resulting distribution, the [logit-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution)

Comment: I put the derivation at the earlier question, since the title uses a more canonical phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $Y$ be the random variable obtained by taking a sigmoid of a normal random variable, $X$.

This means that $\operatorname{logit}(Y)$ is normal.  We might call this a ______ normal random variable.

Here is a another hint:  If $\log(Y)$ is normal, we call $Y$ a *log* normal distribution.  Can you apply the same naming scheme to your problem?

Furthermore, you've just transformed the gaussian density in your example.  Try drawing from a normal and then applying the sigmoid to the draws. Then, plot a histogram.

Comment: i.e., the [Logit-Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution)