# Logit transformation of (asymptotic) normal random variable also (asymptotically) normally distributed?

Tags: logistic, normal-distribution, asymptotics

That is, if X is a (asymptotic) normal random variable, is $ln\left(\frac{X}{1-X} \right)$ also (asymptotically) normally distributed?

From [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62043/distribution-of-a-logit-transform-of-a-normal-variable) question, i suppose it isn't the case but [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2775440) paper seems to state otherwise (although i'm not sure i've understood it as it is)

at page 137 is the proof that the logit transformation of the relative frequency of a binomial random variable (which, asymptotically follows normal distribution) is asymptotically normally distributed.

what i've understood it says is as follows:
let $X\sim B(n,p)$. Then as n goes to infinity, the relative frequency $f=\frac{X}{n} \sim N\left(p,\frac{p(1-p)}{n}\right)$ asymptotically. Since the logit estimater $\hat L = ln(\frac{f}{1-f})$ is a function of $f$ which has a continuous second-order derivative in an interval that contains $f=p$ as an interior point, $\hat L$ is asymptotically normally distributed with a mean equal to the true logit $L=ln(\frac{p}{1-p})$ and a variance equal to the asymptotic variance of $f$ multiplied by the square of the derivative of $\hat L$ with respect to $f$ evaluated at $f=p$.

So basically i don't understand how the fact that $\hat L$ is a function of an asymptotically normal $f$ also makes $\hat L$ asymptotically normal, and also where the asymptotic variance being as such came from. What am I missing here?

Comment: The variances of the estimators decrease to zero, implying eventually you can approximate $x\to\log(1/(1-x))$ as a linear function.  This approximation requires only that this function be differentiable, with nonzero derivative, in a neighborhood of the limiting value of the estimator.

Comment: @whuber Oh.....so is it like ln(x/(1-x)) is asymptotically normal but only as the distribution of ln(x/(1-x)) degenerates to a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be shown by applying twice in a row the [**Delta method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method), first starting from $f_n$ and considering the non-linear function $h_n = h(f_n) = f_n/(1-f_n)$ and then examining the non-linear function $g(h_n) = \ln(h_n)$.

Just remember that "asymptotic distribution" usually refers to a properly centered and scaled function of the core quantity, not the core quantity itself. As $n$ goes to infinity $f_n$ will collapse to a constant. It is the function $\sqrt{n}(f_n - p)$ that will maintain a non-degenerate distribution at the limit.