# Distribution of an RBF-transformed normal variable

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, rbf-kernel

My question might be related to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535578/output-distribution-of-rbf-kernel) or [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62043/distribution-of-a-logit-transform-of-a-normal-variable), but I have reasons to hope my problem is more benign.

Assume I have a normally distributed variable $X \sim  N(0, 1)$. What can be said of $Y = \exp(-\frac{X^2}{2 \sigma^2})$? It is obviously bounded to $(0, 1]$ and it certainly looks like beta-distribution:

[image: Distribution of RBF(sigma=1)-transformed data]

[image: Distribution of RBF(sigma=2)-transformed data]

However, can this be shown mathematically? How do $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depend on $\sigma$? And, assuming that $Y$ is really beta distributed: What if $X$ is multidimensional? I reckon that in that case we'd be dealing with $Y = \exp(-\frac{Z}{2 \sigma^2})$, with $Z$ having a $\chi^2$ distribution. Would $Y$ still have beta distribution and how would degrees of freedom come into play?

Comment: Apply the change of variable formula et voilà!

Comment: Thanks, @Xi'an. I'm sure your comment was well intended, but it actually led me astray. I interpreted it as meaning that by change of variables I'd get to beta-distribution and struggled to see why it kept evading me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on [whuber's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/579493/169343) (+1), I'd like to cover a more general case, as stated in the question. We have a standard normal random variable $X \sim N(0, 1)$. We transform this variable by passing it through an RBF, $Y = \exp(-\frac{X^2}{2 \sigma^2})$. Notice that $\sigma=1$ for $X$, but may be any positive number for $Y$.

Applying the same reasoning as in the referenced answer, it is easy to see that
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{\sigma \cdot y^{\sigma^2-1}}{\sqrt{-\pi\log(y)}}.
$$
Of course, by setting $\sigma = 1$ the formula reduced to the one provided by whuber. Neither formula corresponds to beta distribution, but, interestingly, with the right choice of parameters the approximation is quite good. Below are some examples for different values of $\sigma$:

[image: RBF transformed data for sigma=0.5]

[image: RBF transformed data for sigma=0.75]

[image: RBF transformed data for sigma=1]

[image: RBF transformed data for sigma=1.25]

[image: RBF transformed data for sigma=1.5]

For the reference, here is the code to reproduce the calculations:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.optimize import minimize


# approximate the PDF based on the histogram of X:
def pdf(X):
  h = np.histogram(X, bins=len(X)//100) # the histogram of the data
  x = (h[1][:-1] + h[1][1:])/2          # mid-bin coordinates
  d = (max(h[1]) - min(h[1])) * len(X) / len(h[0])  # dx, for computing the PDF
  return x, h[0]/d
  

# the transform by the Gaussian kernel
def rbf_transform(x, sigma):
  y = np.exp(-x**2/2/sigma**2)
  return y


def transformAndFit(X, sigma, scale='linear', error='abs'):
  Y = rbf_transform(X, sigma)
  y, fY = pdf(Y)
  trueFn = sigma * y**(sigma**2 - 1) / np.sqrt(-np.pi*np.log(y))
  if scale=='linear':
    if error=='abs':
      def objFn(param):
        return np.sum(np.abs(st.beta.pdf(y, param[0], param[1]) - trueFn))
    else:
      def objFn(param):
        return np.sum((st.beta.pdf(y, param[0], param[1]) - trueFn)**2)
  else:
    if error=='abs':
      def objFn(param):
        return np.sum(np.abs(np.log(st.beta.pdf(y, param[0], param[1])) - np.log(trueFn)))
    else:
      def objFn(param):
        return np.sum((np.log(st.beta.pdf(y, param[0], param[1])) - np.log(trueFn))**2)
  
  minFun = np.inf
  alpha = 1.1
  beta  =  .5
  for a in np.arange(.3, 1.3, .1):
    for b in np.arange(.1, .7, .05):
      res = minimize(objFn, [a, b], bounds=((0, None), (0, None)))
      if res.fun < minFun:
        alpha = res.x[0]
        beta  = res.x[1]
  
  plt.plot(y, trueFn, '-', c='steelblue', label='true $f_Y(y)$', lw=2)
  plt.plot(y, fY, '+', c='firebrick', label='simulation')
  plt.plot(y, st.beta.pdf(y, alpha, beta), ':', c='silver', lw=5,
           label=f'B($\\alpha$={alpha:.2f}, $\\beta$={beta:.2f})')
  plt.title(f'RBF($\\sigma$={sigma})-transformed data')
  plt.legend()
  plt.xlabel('y')
  plt.ylabel('$f_Y(y)$')
  if scale == 'log': plt.yscale('log')
  plt.show()


# the starting distribution: standard normal
q = np.linspace(.001, .999, 10000) # 10,000 samples, uniformly over quantiles
X = st.norm.ppf(q)                 # normally distributed samples
x, fX = pdf(X)
plt.plot(x, st.norm.pdf(x), label='theoretical')
plt.plot(x, fX, ':', c='firebrick', label='simulation', lw=3)
plt.title('Original: Standard normal distribution')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# the rbf-transformed data, the true and beta fit:
for sigma in np.arange(.5, 1.5+.25, .25):
  transformAndFit(X, sigma, scale='log')
```

Answer (score 2):

**To get to the essence of this question, let's generalize it a little.**  Suppose $X$ is a random variable supported on a set (of real numbers) $\mathcal A$ where it has a density proportional to

$$f_X(x) = C \exp(-h(x))$$

for some (almost everywhere) differentiable function $h$ defined on $\mathcal A;$ and let $Y = \exp(-h(X)).$

Because $Y$ is a (differentiable) transformation of $X,$ it also is a continuous random variable.  Let's find its density.  To do so, we must analyze the entire *probability element* by changing the variable in $f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x$ to $y = \exp(-h(x)).$  One key calculation is the new differential

$$\mathrm{d}y = \mathrm{d}\left(\exp(-h(x))\right) = -\exp(-h(x))h^\prime(x)\mathrm{d}x = -y h^\prime(x) \mathrm{d}x,$$

from which we may equate a differential form in $y$ with a differential form in $x$ *via*

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{y} = -h^\prime(x)\mathrm{d}x.$$

Exploit this to compute

$$f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x = C\exp(-h(x)) |\mathrm{d}x| = Cy \bigg|\frac{-1}{h^\prime(x)} \frac{\mathrm d y}{y} \bigg| = \frac{C}{|h^\prime(x)|}\mathrm{d}y.$$

We have to deal with the $h^\prime(x)$ term on the right: it needs to be expressed in terms of $y.$  Consider any possible value $y$ of $Y.$  Corresponding to it *via* the transformation $h$ is the set of $x,$ written $h^{-1}(y),$ that $h$ maps to this particular $y.$  Because $h$ is differentiable, $h^{-1}(y)$ is at most countable and from the previous equality we obtain

> $$f_Y(y) = C\sum_{x\ \in\ h^{-1}(y)} \frac{1}{|h^\prime(x)|}.\tag{*}$$

That's almost as far as we can take the analysis at this level of generality, so let's specialize to the case of the question where $h(x) = x^2 / (2\sigma^2)$ and $\mathcal A$ is the set of real numbers.  Taking the derivative is easy; $$h^\prime(x) = x/\sigma^2.$$  The image of $h$ is the set of non-negative numbers, almost all of which are positive.  When $y$ is a positive number, there are *two* corresponding $x$ values obtained by solving

$$y = h(x) = \exp(-x^2/(2\sigma^2));\quad x = \pm \sigma\sqrt{-2\log(y)}.$$

The general formula $(*)$ and the fact $C = 1/(|\sigma|\sqrt{2\pi})$ gives

$$\begin{aligned}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{C}{|h^\prime( \sigma\sqrt{-2\log(y)} )|} +  \frac{C}{|h^\prime(-\sigma\sqrt{-2\log(y)} )|} \\
&= \frac{C\sigma^2}{|\sigma\sqrt{-2\log(y)} |} +  \frac{C\sigma^2}{|-\sigma\sqrt{-2\log(y)}|} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\pi\log(y)}}.
\end{aligned}$$

(It's easy to show in general that any scale factor $\sigma$ in $f_X$ will disappear in the final formula.)

Here is a histogram of one million draws of $Y,$ on which the plot of $f_Y$ is superimposed in red to show their close agreement.

[image: Figure]

Notice that this does *not* give rise to any Beta distribution: near $0$ it does not behave like any distribution in that family.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. I don't get your last sentence: Your graph is practically identical to my first figure, with $B(\alpha=1.1, \beta=0.4)$. I see that the mathematical formula is not in any way related to Beta, but the curve is quite similar.

Comment: Take a closer look at the behavior near zero and one. The similarity is due to the reciprocal square-root behavior near $1.$  That vertical asymptote shows that if this were a Beta distribution, its second parameter *must* be $1/2.$ The limiting value of $0$ at $0$ shows the first parameter must exceed $1.$ You can obtain an excellent approximation with the parameters $1.14$ and $1/2$--but nevertheless, the logarithmic term cannot exactly equal a rational function (which all Beta pdfs are).  Look at graphs on a log scale.

Comment: Re your edit: I rolled it back because it is incorrect.  As I have pointed out, my expression for $f_Y$ is fully general.